# Sequential numbers in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Does MarkLogic have a feature to generate unique sequential number, equivalent to sequences in Oracle database?

Comment: Provide an example of the feature or solution you need and include what you have tried. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please describe better what you want to do using marklogic (e.g. you want to use a primary key etc) and give an example on your use case. This will help others to suggest you alternative solutions.

Comment: @sanastasiadis - i need a requirement like where i can replace oracle sequence with Marklogic ..... ,, but what need to use not sure ,,

Comment: The notion of Oracle sequences is well established. I don't think there is anything wrong with this question, apart from being a little terse..

Answer (score 2):

Oracle sequences generate unique numbers. But generating unique numbers in sequence will hold you back, as it prevents the possibility of inserting data in parallel. Instead, it is recommended to use random ids.

This little library joins best practices for generating random database uris in MarkLogic. I recommend using that:

https://github.com/grtjn/ml-unique

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for information. Have some query on this.  1. Can you tell if this unique id generate numbers in sequence like 1.2.3,4,5 ... etc and i can define a max value too.   2. If it is generate random ids only can we query about what was the last id .

Comment: No, it doesn't generate numbers/uris in sequence (as was said, to allow for parallelized inserts). Why do you need the last id? Is it to know the most recent record created? That can be accomplished with a timestamp and date range index...

Comment: Using sequential numbers for identifiers is considered a bad practice anyhow, because it is too easy to predict.